# Z-stacking CSS 3 Flex boxes : how to overlay DIVs that are flexbox items?

Tags: css, flexbox

Haven't managed to stack divs when creating a flexbox layout. Either they push each other within the container div, or I have to use `"position:absolute"` on the overlay which gets the div out of its container context.

z-indices seem to not work at all.

I am using chrome latest version and was expecting this behaviour: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/#painting

Here is a plunker with a basic flexbox layout:
http://plnkr.co/edit/o2BAwvg3XV4YjwAwwmYR?p=preview to illustrate.

You will have to comment/uncomment the positioning in the definition of the `.overlay` class which is in the css.

Comment: In Firefox 23, it seems to work as expected for me. Without `position:absolute`, the overlay div takes the most part of `.bodybox` except of its text, because it comes after the text. With positioning, it is in the root stacking context (because `.bodybox` has no `z-index`) and overlays all non-positioned divs, but can be overlayed by header or footer if they get `z-index: 100` or more.

Comment: Yes, the fact that the text is an anonymous flex item is actually annoying. Otherwise, I could just use the overlay div as a child of the text flex item. Something like that. That would solve the problem in Chrome. I guess will have to wait until the behaviours are harmonized between the different browser vendors.

Comment: Why do you think that non-positioned overlay becomes a flex item? My observations show that it is a regular block box in the flex item, inheriting its width and height from `.bodybox`: http://plnkr.co/edit/29zPsZ?p=preview

Comment: You are right it is a mistake. I thought I had made .bodybox a flex box. In which case .overlay would be a flex item. The behaviour is still weird to me in Chrome though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, just realized z-index only works with **positioned** elements.

In the case presented, I needed to set the height of the container of the div .overlay (just put height:100% in .bodybox)

All is good now.

Comment: Plunker for the solution please.

Comment: Please add a plunker displaying the solution if you are going to mark you own answer as correct :)

Comment: Plz *_* Listen to the others!